# change the command ids default handler

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I need to change the command id's default handler . For example RestartWorkbenchHandler's command id is org.eclipse.ui.file.restart. So when we give the command is org.eclipse.ui.file.restart it will call the RestartWorkbenchHandler.
Now I wanted to restrict not to call the RestartWorkbenchHandler instead it should call my own Handlers when I give the org.eclipse.ui.file.restart. How do I do that?

Thanks
Bhanu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That handler is provided as the default handler (priority==0) for that command.  AFAIK, though, the ID is **org.eclipse.ui.file.restartWorkbench**.

You can override it by providing another handler with a higher priority.  You can use `org.eclipse.ui.handlers`:

```
  <handler class="org.example.YourResetHandler"
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.restartWorkbench">
     <activeWhen>
        <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow">
           <instanceof value="org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow"/>
        </with>
     </activeWhen>
  </handler>
```

Or you can simply register another handler in your `ActionBarAdvisor` while making legacy actions:

```
    IHandlerService srv = (IHandlerService) window.getService(IHandlerService.class);
    srv.activateHandler(IWorkbenchCommandConstants.FILE_RESTART, new YourRestartHandler());
```

Comment: Hi Paul Thanks for the information.I would like to ask you one more question. My project, it is not rcp application. It is eclipe workbench application. In that case how do I do it? How do I add the code which you gave?

Comment: In the IDE 1) you better not kill my **File>Restart** :-) and 2) you would have to use the plugin.xml method, as you don't provide the `ActionBarAdvisor`

Comment: there we need to add one confirm messagebox before restarting.That is the requirement.